# The face recognition package not have package.xml file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got face recognition tutorial on ros wiki page:

[www.ros.org/wiki/face_recognition](http://www.ros.org/wiki/face_recognition)

and the SVN link for the face recognition package:

github.com/procrob/procrob_functional/tree/master/face_recognition

I tried to build the workspace using catkin_make command on groovy. But it not building the face recognition package. I had noticed that the package.xml file not exist in the face recognition package.

How I can run this node in groovy?

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73651/the-face-recognition-package-not-have-package.xml-file/) by [Sreejith](https://answers.ros.org/users/5533/sreejith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has a stack.xml -- so it is still a rosmake package. You should build it using rosmake instead of catkin. For details on mixing rosmake and catkin workspaces see: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html#mixing-catkin-and-rosbuild-workspaces

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2